# Looking for 4 bit memory option

Tags: integrated-circuit, memory, eeprom

I'm building a small and simple 4-bit CPU and I'm looking for an IC to store the program opcodes.  I've considered using eeproms although they seem too large for my purpose, being in the kilobyte range.  I was hoping that there was an easy to access memory that stored 8 bit numbers and could be addressed using 4 bit values, or 16 addressable 8 bit values.  I would also prefer not to have to purchase an eeprom programmer so that memory could easily be programmed with a micro-controller.

What type of memory IC would be recommended for this purpose?

Comment: What sort of implementation technology are you using for your CPU? Are we talking discrete transistors, SSI/MSI logic, CPLD?

Comment: I am using TTL and CMOS integrated circuits for each part of my cpu

Comment: http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?pv142=129&pv142=496&pv142=566&pv142=571&pv142=382&pv142=1065&pv142=384&pv142=887&pv142=893&pv142=880&pv142=868&pv142=886&pv142=1079&pv142=278&pv142=877&pv142=1086&pv142=875&pv142=281&pv142=1087&pv142=876&pv142=1088&pv142=284&pv142=286&pv142=1123&pv142=343&pv142=563&pv142=866&pv142=1102&FV=fff40027%2Cfff80434&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25

Comment: Also, why not use a much faster MCU to act as the memory instead? That way you can use either the MCU programmer or a bootloader to program it. Plus it'd be cheaper and easier to find.

Comment: I'm making a collection of all known TTL computers at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Microprocessor_Design/Wire_Wrap . I'd love to add your CPU to the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you want to build as much as possible yourself.
So why not also build your own the ROM?

It is easily possible if you have just 2^4 data words.
You can use two [74HC138](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls138.pdf) to decode the address and feed the outputs into a diode array.

Here is a schematic with just one 138 (but another one can be added for 8 more data words; it must be enabled by connecting A3 to the non-inverted enable input; another possibility would be to use a single [74HC4067](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd74hc4067.pdf) (16 channel analog MUX/DEMUX)). 
A diode has to be placed at the appropriate crossing for each 0-bit.
(If you have more 0-bits than 1-bits use a 74HC240 buffer instead of a 74HC244 and put a diode for each 1-bit).

[image]

Comment: Yes, [diode matrix ROM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/diode_matrix) is a part of many early computers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want **nonvolatility** and simple parallel output and input of address, an EEPROM would probably be the easiest for you.

An [Atmel 28C64](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc0270.pdf) is less than $4 in singles, still available through authorized distributors, requires only a single +5V supply, and holds 8K x 8 bits. Easily programmed with a microcontroller, comes in DIP-28 package if you want, and is reasonably fast. Just don't bother about the unused bytes.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious candidate is the 74LS189. 16 x 4 bits, LSTTL. Available for ~ $3.00.

Comment: Do you know why the 74LS189 has outputs that complement the content of the addressed memory location? What is the benefit?

Comment: Haven't a clue. Not the faintest idea.

Comment: The 74LS189 is a RAM. The OP obviously is looking for some kind of ROM (non-volatile).